# How to Centre code output (text) to the middle of a page using Knitr pdf output?

Tags: r, alignment, r-markdown, markdown, center

I am having a problem with center aligning in code output chunks in knitr when knitting to PDF.

For example, if I run the following:

````
---
title: "TRIAL"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{sectsty}
   - \allsectionsfont{\color{cyan}}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

\setlength{\leftskip}{7cm} 

## R Markdown

\setlength{\leftskip}{0cm}
This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. 

```{r cars}
options(width = 80)
summary(cars)
```
````

I would like all output of summary(cars) to be center aligned.

Comment: In your YAML header you compile to PDF, not HTML. So what do you mean?

Comment: @J_F.. apologies.. i meant pdf.. query edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the fact that your output is of class `table` you can use the following workaround (note to install the two libraries `kableExtra` and `knitr`):

```
library(kableExtra)
library(knitr)

kable_styling(kable(summary(cars)), position = "center")
```

[image]

In addition to that I highly recommend the following PDF: https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf

If you want to center text:

```
\begin{center}
 centered text
\end{center}
```

Comment: Thank you.. This works.. though not exactly as expected.. The reference guide is helpful..

Comment: Does this work only for tables or for text ? I tried centering some text data obtained through mail merge.. it does not process it.

Comment: the above center text code doesn't work if it's a header.